# How to show my current location using mapbox SDK?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, mapbox

I'm trying to use the mapbox SDK to get my current location and set the navigation, but it's not working. I was trying to implement this code following the tutorial from the mapbox website.

```
public class pos extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener {


    private MapView mapView;


    // variables for adding location layer
    private MapboxMap map;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationLayerPlugin locationPlugin;
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private Location originLocation;


    // variables for adding a marker
    private Marker destinationMarker;
    private LatLng originCoord;
    private LatLng destinationCoord;


    // variables for calculating and drawing a route
    private Point originPosition;
    private Point destinationPosition;
    private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
    private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";
    private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;


    //private Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this,"pk.eyJ1IjoiaWhkaW5hIiwiYSI6ImNqaDRveHdhcjB1ZTIyd253M2R2MGhwY28ifQ.If9oJq_rILeuaK1sjp9-nw");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pos);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {


                map = mapboxMap;
                enableLocationPlugin();


                originCoord = new LatLng(originLocation.getLatitude(), originLocation.getLongitude());
                mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
                        if (destinationMarker != null) {
                            mapboxMap.removeMarker(destinationMarker);
                        }
                        destinationCoord = point;
                        destinationMarker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(destinationCoord)
                        );


                        destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(destinationCoord.getLongitude(), destinationCoord.getLatitude());
                        originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originCoord.getLongitude(), originCoord.getLatitude());
                        getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);


                       /* button.setEnabled(true);
                        button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);*/


                    }

                    ;
                });


                /*button = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Point origin = originPosition;
                        Point destination = destinationPosition;
                        // Pass in your Amazon Polly pool id for speech synthesis using Amazon Polly
                        // Set to null to use the default Android speech synthesizer
                        String awsPoolId = null;
                        boolean simulateRoute = true;
                        NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                                .origin(origin)
                                .destination(destination)
                                .awsPoolId(awsPoolId)
                                .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                                .build();

                        // Call this method with Context from within an Activity
                        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(NavigationActivity.this, options);
                    }
                });*/


            }

            ;
        });


    }


    private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) {
        NavigationRoute.builder()
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                        if (response.body() == null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                            return;
                        } else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                            return;
                        }

                        currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                        // Draw the route on the map
                        if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                            navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                        } else {
                            navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                        }
                        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                    }



                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }


    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void enableLocationPlugin() {
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
            // Create an instance of LOST location engine
            initializeLocationEngine();

            locationPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map, locationEngine);
            locationPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(true);
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void initializeLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.activate();

        Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            originLocation = lastLocation;
            setCameraPosition(lastLocation);
        } else {
            locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        }
    }

    private void setCameraPosition(Location location) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocationPlugin();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    public void onConnected() {
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            originLocation = location;
            setCameraPosition(location);
            locationEngine.removeLocationEngineListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationPlugin != null) {
            locationPlugin.onStart();
        }
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationPlugin != null) {
            locationPlugin.onStop();
        }
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.deactivate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get errors, etc.?

Comment: No i dont get any error , just i get a map like when u want to try if its working or no

Comment: i dont get my current location in the map

Comment: removed noise, annoying double spaces

Comment: "it's not working" is not working. You need to explain the difference between expected and actual outcome and reduce the code to the minimum demonstrating the issue.